# plotting very large data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot a large set of values against time. My dataset spans over 46 days and includes data for every second of the day. Since the plots are incomprehensible when plotted directly, I tried to group them. the groupby function in pandas works fine as long as one needs to find some aggregates or summary statistics. I tried the following command, but it just gives a blop on the plot and does not do what I want it to.

df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='7D'))['values']

Is there a way to group the data according to a column and then add it in a new column?

I also tried plots after making time the index, but that also does not help.

Comment: `df.resample("1D").max()`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Won't it just give me all the max score values for each of the days (groups)?